this.props.map is not a function when trying to modify state component
I have an input and a button. When button is clicked I expect it to add the data inside the states, and then display it at the screen. I created states in the parent constructor and also added one sample in the arrays to be sure that function is working. And the problem is that when web-app is launched - everything renders fine. But when I click on button and try to add text in these arrays - it crashes and says : "this.props.elements.map is not a function". But at the time of launch everything worked fine. Here is the code :
class Request_template extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            logs : [{id : uuidv4(), text : "Hello world"}],
            notes : [{id : uuidv4(), text : "Hello world"}],
            textfield : ""
        }
    }

    update_textfield = (event) => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {textfield : event.target.value}
        })
    }

    add_note_and_log = () => {
        const value = this.state.textfield;
        this.setState({
            logs : this.state.logs.push({
                id : uuidv4(),
                desc : value
            }),
            notes : this.state.notes.push({
                id : uuidv4(),
                desc : value
            }),
            textfield : ""
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='request-grid-holder'>
                <span className='request-grid-holder__id'>1</span>
                <Status_selector/>
                <span className='request-grid-holder__name'>Vin</span>
                <span className='request-grid-holder__email'>anon92993@gmail.com</span>
                <span className='request-grid-holder__self'>I am the customer</span>
                <span className='request-grid-holder__added'>2024-03-29 10:53:08</span>
                <NoteAdd updater={this.update_textfield} writer={this.add_note_and_log}/>
                <DoubleListFlex logs={this.state.logs} notes={this.state.notes}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

In this part in constructor I initialize state for textfield + logs + notes. And create a function add_note_and_log() so it would modify the states and pass it as props to the NoteAdd component.
class NoteAdd extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="note-field-flex-box">
                <input type="text" className="note-field-flex-box__input" onChange={this.props.updater}/>
                <button
                    className="note-field-flex-box__button"
                    onClick={this.props.writer}>Add
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

In this component I create an input and a button, when button is clicked - I try to change states using input value.
class DoubleListFlex extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="double-collapsible-holder">
                <ListFlexDisplay newElements={this.props.notes} buttonTitle="Пометки"/>
                <ListFlexDisplay newElements={this.props.logs} buttonTitle="Логи"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

It's a holder for lists which are holding and present elements from state.
class ListFlexDisplay extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="collapsible-container">
                <button className="collapsible-container__activator" onClick={
                    console.log(this.props.elements)
                }>{this.props.buttonTitle}</button>
                <div className="collapsible-container__content">
                    {
                        this.props.newElements.map(object => {
                            return (
                                <h1 key={object.id} className='styled-content'>{object.text}</h1>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

It's the most problematic part. When I try to add elements from input, "this.props.newElements.map" is crashing with error "this.props.map is not a function".
I've been sitting and trying to solve it for 3-4 hours. Googled and tried other answers with the same problem - it didn't help. The main problem is that when I launch it with "npm start" it displays the elements correctly and works fine. But it breaks when I try to add a new element and update the state.

Your setState replaces notes and logs with the return value of Array#push (the new length of the array) and you can't well map over the integer. Instead of push, use the spread operator:
this.setState({
            logs : [...this.state.logs, {
                id : uuidv4(),
                desc : value
            }],
            // etc... 


Thank u! U saved my day, everything works fine now. I should've asked this question 2 hours before
